# Show that with these properties a topology is defined on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a hausdorff-space.

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology

On the set $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\,\cup\,\{-\infty,\infty\}$ a topology is defined as: A subset $U\subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is open if the following requirements are fulfilled:

(i) $\,$ $U \cap \mathbb{R}$ is open in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$

(ii) $\,$ If $\infty \in U$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $]r,\infty[ \subset U$.

(iii) $\,$ If $-\infty \in U$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $]-\infty,r[ \subset U$.

Show that with these properties a topology is defined on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a hausdorff-space.   A housedorff-space is a topological space where for any two distinct points there exist neighbourhoods of each which are disjoint from each other

A task from an old Analysis II exam, where unfortunately I don't have any clue on how to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing we need to show is that we can separate $+\infty$ (and $-\infty$) from the points of non-extended reals. Let us think about $+\infty$. Conditions (i) and (ii) guarantee that every interval $]b,+\infty]$ is open. Hence to separate $a$ and $+\infty$ it is enough to take, say, $]a-1,a+1[$ and $]a+2,+\infty]$.

The rest is similar.